# How do I implement the function of logout action goes back to login page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have a issue regarding the logout function implementation.

As you may see in codesandbox, my App has became with this appearance: https://sit9d.csb.app/login

Here is the Logout.js code I imagine it's where possibly I will edit:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setAuthedUser } from '../actions/authedUser'

class Logout extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setAuthedUser(null)
    }

    render() {
        return<div>Logging out...</div>
    }
}

export default connect(
    null,
    { setAuthedUser }
)(Logout)
```

Here is the navigation bar, Menu.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class Menu extends Component {
    render() {
        const { users, authedUser } = this.props
        const { name, avatarURL } = users[authedUser]

        return (
            <div className='ui fixed inverted menu'>
                <div className='ui container'>
                    <div className='item' />
                    <NavLink
                        to='/'
                        exact
                        className='header item'
                        activeClassName='active'
                    >
                        <Image
                            src='/would-you-rather.png'
                            style={{ width: '50px', marginRight: '5px' }}
                         />
                         Home
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to='/add' exact className='item' activeClassName='active'>
                        New Question
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink
                        to='/leaderboard'
                        exact
                        className='item'
                        activeClassName='active'
                    >
                        Leader Board
                    </NavLink>
                    <div className='ui right floated item'>
                        <span style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}>Hello, {name}</span>
                        <img className='ui avatar image' src={avatarURL} alt='' />
                    </div>
                    <NavLink to='/logout' exact className='item' activeClassName='active'>
                        Logout
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { authedUser: state.authedUser, users: state.users }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Menu)
```

I'd like to know how could I implement the function of the logout goes back to the login authentication page?

Please any help, I'd appreciate.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `this.props.history.push('/login')` right after resetting your user in `componentDidMount`.

`history` is provided to `Logout.js` by `react-router-dom`, since it is a route component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setAuthedUser } from '../actions/authedUser'

class Logout extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setAuthedUser(null)
        this.props.history.push('/login')
    }

    render() {
        return<div>Logging out...</div>
    }
}

export default connect(
    null,
    { setAuthedUser }
)(Logout)
```

Comment: Hi, @CoreyLarson, thanks for your answer. Would I need to implement `history` in Logout.js component?

Comment: @jose-renato-m, You shouldn't need to. Because `<Logout />` is a route in your application, `history` is provided to it as a prop.

Comment: Sorry, @CoreyLarson......I haven"t seen you put there the `history` code. I'll try.

Comment: Sorry @jose-renato-m, I should have made this more clear in the answer. Will update it.